# What is "projectkey" in sonar-project.properties file

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

## What is the "projectkey" in sonar-project.properties file?

```
sonar.projectKey= 

sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.projectName=
```

How to decide the projectkey? I mean where can we find it for our `.Net`,`plsql projects`?

Note- I am new to these sonar and trying to setup all these on my own in my organization.

Answer (score 18):

projectKey is simply the unique identifier of your project inside SonarQube. You are free to choose whatever you want, as long as it is unique.

[Analysis Parameters](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/analysis-parameters/) is the official documentation page from Sonar, where you can find additional information about all the properties.